# Is there a way to move Vertex Groups with Geometry Nodes fields?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

Using the 2.9 approach of attributes, I saw this accomplished by a couple of Attribute Vector Math nodes, like so:
[image]

Another example:
[image]
[image]

With the introduction of Geometry Nodes fields, I can't find a way to get this same functionality of moving a targeted user-defined vertex group. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 8):

If your question is: 'How do I access a vertex-group in Geometry Nodes (Fields)?' ...

This answer may be a bit premature, but at the time of writing, named attributes appear to be considered external to the tree? I can't find a 'Named Attribute' input node. Instead, [you can expose the attribute as a group input, in the modifier](https://youtu.be/Yci5ouEmnLI?t=1025):

[image]

By clicking on the spreadsheet icon on the left of the field in the modifier, you will be offered a list of available attribute-inputs. You can also type, or copy-paste the entry, if you like.

[image]

However hard this is to deduce atm :), it does make sense. The attributes are of-the-mesh, not of-the-modifier.

Comment: This does the job, thanks. Yeah, I've yet to find a way to target a vertex group in Fields without the use of a Group Input node, which sadly clutters up the modifier panel with unnecessary information. Let's hope they'll address this sooner or later!

Comment: @LittleAden   I think that may be deliberate, for the reason given in the answer?  You're supposed to be able to re-use the modifier, share it with others. This arrangement reduces the risk of failure when it's assigned  to an object which doesn't have the required named attribute, and makes it more flexible. What a programmer would call 'Decoupling'.

Comment: That's understandable... The node graphs I make are usually as purpose driven as the models they're married to, so hiding some bells and whistles would still be nice for them. But this does make me question if I've been using GeoNodes shortsightedly haha

Answer (score 4):

You can change the cone height just like that:

[image]

Use Mesh Primitives -> Cone and change the depth.

If you are asking for something else, please ask for more specific. I assumed you wanted to change the height of the cone because of your screenshot.

Comment: Right! So as the title mentioned, the question was specifically aimed at vertex group movement. I added another example to the question to further highlight this. Sorry for the confusion.